# VULKAN fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm working on getting Vulkan installed and working functionally.
I keep running into the error

"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory"

Here's the code I have so far:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
#include <glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I'm on Windows 11.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

I've set the project properties C++ language as "C++20".

I've also included the correct libraries that are also labeled lib-vc2022.

Comment: So you are saying that you _don't_ get this error if you include only `<iostream>`? Is this the minimal example producing the error? What settings exactly did you modify in Visual Studio? What libraries did you install and how? Is the error from the compiler or just the IDE's code analysis?

Comment: I deleted the code and now I just have 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   return0;
}

I'm now getting a different error:

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h'

I'm thinking it must be something with the compiler but I'm unsure how to change it and I've been googling this for the past 4 hours.

The settings I changed are in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2jkALhm9EE

basically just adding libraries


The only settings I changed was c++ language

Comment: Then something is not right with your Visual Studio installation. So the question has nothing really to do with Vulkan. I don't use Visual Studio, so I can't help you with that. I would recommend that you remove Visual Studio and try to install it again, e.g. following Microsoft's instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=msvc-170) (see also other guides on the left-hand side), then create a new empty project without Vulkan/GLFW and test the above program that includes only `<iostream>`.

Comment: After a fresh install following the instructions I still have the same error, any idea what it could be?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-crtdbgh/982183

Comment: I fixed it, here's what I did:

redownload visual studio

choose only desktop c++ and gaming.

on the right I also choose the lastest windows 11 sdk.